# Hive and Impala showing different roles for user with Sentry installed

Tags: hive, cloudera, impala, apache-sentry

I am running Cloudera 5.15, with Kerboros enabled on the cluster. Sentry is installed to configure user access to various tables/databases ...etc.

Everything is installed and working fine for Hive, but not for Impala.

I'm using Hue web UI for issuing hive/impala queries. (I'm getting same results using beeline and impala-shell though)

From Hue/Hive:

> show current roles;

return --> "professors_role"

From Hue/Impala

> show current roles;

return --> no results

When I issue "select current_user()" from hive and impala query editors I'm getting different results.

From hive "select current_user()" returns "hive"

from impala "select current_user()" returns "professor1"

I'm thinking perhaps this is the kulprit, but i'm not sure how to fix? Maybe I've missed a configuration setting in impala somewhere?

Everything works fine in hive - logging in as different users shows me different databases and tables as I would expect based on their assigned roles. Users logged into Impala can't see anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: great answer by xiaohei
to complet his answer, your hue use impalad that is installed in same machine with hue server, so you should have same user/group on impala statestore , impalad and hue server machines, or use one machine for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, but I fix it now.
You can check which machine you install the impala statestore, and you must have the same impala user/group on the linux system.